# Changing Vala or GTK version to compile

Tags: gtk, vala

Bit of a newbie question, but I am trying to build [Writer](https://code.launchpad.net/~writer-devs/writer/trunk) to play around with. I followed the build/installation instructions , but am getting the following error:

```
CMakeFiles/writer.dir/src/Widgets/TableToolBar.c.o: In function `writer_widgets_table_tool_bar_construct':
/home/cameron/Sites/writer-dev/install/src/Widgets/TableToolBar.c:405: undefined reference to `gtk_widget_set_focus_on_click'
CMakeFiles/writer.dir/src/Widgets/TextToolBar.c.o: In function `writer_widgets_text_tool_bar_setup_ui':
/home/cameron/Sites/writer-dev/install/src/Widgets/TextToolBar.c:442: undefined reference to `gtk_widget_set_focus_on_click'
/home/cameron/Sites/writer-dev/install/src/Widgets/TextToolBar.c:456: undefined reference to `gtk_widget_set_focus_on_click'
/home/cameron/Sites/writer-dev/install/src/Widgets/TextToolBar.c:470: undefined reference to `gtk_widget_set_focus_on_click'
/home/cameron/Sites/writer-dev/install/src/Widgets/TextToolBar.c:484: undefined reference to `gtk_widget_set_focus_on_click'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/writer.dir/build.make:612: recipe for target 'writer' failed
make[2]: *** [writer] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/writer.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/writer.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

[A bit of googling](https://github.com/baedert/corebird/issues/531) seems to indicate that this is caused by my GTK3 version (3.18.9-1ubuntu3.1) and my Vala version (0.34.4 0ubuntu1~16.04~valateam1) having some sort of conflict with `gtk_widget_set_focus_on_click`. What's the best way to resolve this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be much better answered by the developers of Writer here https://answers.launchpad.net/writer